# Is there any way to auto translate the whole react native app

Tags: json, react-native, language-translation

I want to **translate** the complete app into any other language without using **JSON** files like **ar.json**, **en.json** like it is possible in **Websites** by using **google translate**.

I want to know it is possible in **React Native** somehow. If possible then how can we translate the whole app language in any other language without Prepare language **JSON** files like we can do in **Websites**.

I'm new to react native development and want to know this. I searched a lot for this but could not found helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no such way for auto translating the app without exclusively make language files (JSON). React i18Next is a really good library for it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you not to use a library but a simple context provider would do.

```
import React from 'react';

const lang = {
  // in this way, you could dynamically add lang
  // later on which worrying about if-elses in your component
  en: {
    hello: 'hello'
  },
  fr: {
    hello: 'bonjour',
  },
}

const langDict = (key) => lang[key]

const LanguageContext = React.createContext(null);

function LanguageProvider({ initialState = 'en', children }) {
  const [lang, setLang] = React.useState(initialState);

  return (
    <LanguageContext.Provider value={[langDict(lang), setLang]}>
      {children}
    </LanguageContext.Provider>
  )
}

function useLanguage() {
  return React.useContext(LanguageContext);
}

export default function AppWrapper() {
  return (
    <LanguageProvider>
        <App />
    </LanguageProvider>
  )
}

function App() {
  const [lang, setLang] = useLanguage();

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{lang.hello}</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => setLang('fr')}>French</Button>
      <Button onPress={() => setLang('en')}>English</Button>
    </VIew>
  )
}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 1):

Great question. The answers depend on what type of translation you’re talking about. Is this free flowing, conversational text that’s variable? If so, the translations will be variable and may not say what you want it to say. Or, if this is just a series of app labels, help info, or context info? If so, you’ll likely be better off doing just switching either separate files or json switches as others have stated. More clarification is needed.

Comment: I want to translate the complete app text into any other language which user wants as web developers do in Websites by using Google Translate API.