# React-Native multi language app with Google Translation API

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there any way to translate the dynamic string fast with google translation to any other language. I already did some R&D on it and not able to find the solution.

There will be huge data to translate, most of them coming in the API response.

One SDK I found is this [AWS Client Translate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-translate/index.html)
but I prefer google first.

Some of the StackOverflow posts which I've already seem but they are without the solution:

1. [FIRST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63777392/is-there-any-way-to-auto-translate-the-whole-react-native-app)
2. [SECOND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63375478/translate-dynamic-data-into-multiple-language-in-react-native)

this two links. Please guide